# Can't read HttpResponseMessage content when the status code is not success

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have a service which is consuming an SMS REST API using `HttpClient`:

```cs
HttpClient http = this._httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
// Skipped: setup HttpRequestMessage
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await http.SendAsync(request))
{
    try
    {
        _ = response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException)
    {
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // Fails with ObjectDisposedException
        this._logger.LogInformation(
            "Received invalid HTTP response status '{0}' from SMS API. Response content was {1}.",
            (int)response.StatusCode,
            responseString
        );
        throw;
    }
}
```

The API returns an error, but I would like to be able to log it. So I need to log both the failing status code (which I can read from `response.StatusCode`) and the associated content (which may contain additional error useful details).

This code fails on the instruction `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` with this exception:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent'.
>       Module "System.Net.Http.HttpContent", in CheckDisposed
>       Module "System.Net.Http.HttpContent", in ReadAsStringAsync

Some sources suggest that you shouldn't read the response content when the status code is not in the success range (200-299), but what if the response really contains useful error details?

.NET version used: .NET Core 2.1.12 on AWS lambda linux runtime.

Comment: Why not read the content before throwing the exception? Then pass the content to the exception so you can access it in your catch block.

Comment: Are you implying `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` is disposing the response?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, apparently this is [a known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26684) in the .NET API, which has been addressed in .NET Core 3.0. `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` is actually disposing the response content. It was implemented this way to supposedly help users:

> // Disposing the content should help users: If users call EnsureSuccessStatusCode(), an exception is
>   // thrown if the response status code is != 2xx. I.e. the behavior is similar to a failed request (e.g.
>   // connection failure). Users don't expect to dispose the content in this case: If an exception is
>   // thrown, the object is responsible fore cleaning up its state.

This is an undesirable behavior which was removed from 3.0. In the meantime, I just switched to use `IsSuccessStatusCode` before the log:

```cs
HttpClient http = this._httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
// Skipped: setup HttpRequestMessage
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await http.SendAsync(request))
{
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // Fails with ObjectDisposedException
        this._logger.LogInformation(
            "Received invalid HTTP response status '{0}' from SMS API. Response content was {1}.",
            (int)response.StatusCode,
            responseString
        );
        _ = response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

A little bit more redundant, but it should work.